# CppRestSDK https request not working

Tags: https, speech-to-text, bing, bing-api, azure-cognitive-services

This is returning error code `401` or `500`. Can somebody help me where I am going wrong?

```
http_client client(L"https://oxford-speech.cloudapp.net/token/issueToken/");    
uri_builder query;
query.append_query(L"grant_type", L"client_credentials");       
query.append_query(L"client_id", L"test-app");
query.append_query(L"client_secret", L"<client secret goes here>");
query.append_query(L"scope", L"https://speech.platform.bing.com");
query.append_query(L"content_type", L"application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

http_request msg(methods::POST);
msg.headers().set_content_type(L"application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
msg.set_request_uri(query.to_string());

std::wstring str = msg.to_string();
return client.request(msg);
```

Comment: I removed your client-secret and you might want to re-generate it.

Comment: Thanks. Did not get the reason though the same query works in other JS clinet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all. I changed the code to following and i got the token!

```
pplx::task<void> getAccessToken()
{
istream bodyStream;
http_client client(L"https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken");
http_request req(methods::POST);
req.headers().add(L"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", L"YOUR_KEY");

return client.request(req)

.then([](http_response response)
{
    if (response.status_code() != status_codes::OK)
    {
        return pplx::task_from_result();
    }
    istream bodyStream = response.body();
    container_buffer<std::string> inStringBuffer;       
    return bodyStream.read_line(inStringBuffer)

.then([inStringBuffer](size_t bytesRead)
{
    const std::string &text = inStringBuffer.collection();
    std::cout << text;
});

});
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generic JSON representation of a request that worked last time I tried (Sept 2016). Your request looks pretty different. Extracted from [Woundify settings file](https://github.com/BSalita/Woundify/blob/master/WoundifyShared/WoundifyDefaultSettings.json)

```
{
  "name": "BingSpeechToTextService",
  "classInterface": "BingServices.ISpeechToTextService",
  "request": {
    "method": "post", // { "get" | "post" | <custom> }
    "preferChunkedEncodedRequests": false,
    "uri": {
      "scheme": "https",
      "host": "speech.platform.bing.com",
      "path": "recognize",
      "query": "scenarios=smd&appid=D4D52672-91D7-4C74-8AD8-42B1D98141A5&locale={locale}&device.os=wp7&version=3.0&format=json&instanceid=565D69FF-E928-4B7E-87DA-9A750B96D9E3&requestid={guid}"
    },
    "headers": [
      {
        "Name": "Accept",
        "Accept": "application/json"
      },
      {
        "Name": "BearerAuthentication",
        "BearerAuthentication": {
          "type": "bearer", // { basic | bearer | <custom> }
          "clientID": "",
          "clientSecret": "",
          "scope": "https://speech.platform.bing.com",
          "uri": "https://oxford-speech.cloudapp.net/token/issueToken",
          "grant": "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={clientID}&client_secret={clientSecret}&scope={scope}"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Content-Type",
        "ContentType": "audio/wav; codec=\"audio/pcm\"; samplerate={sampleRate}"
      }
    ],
    "data": {
      "type": "binary" // { ascii | base64 | binary | json | raw | string | urlencode }
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "missingResponse": "whatever",
    "jsonPath": "results[0].name"
  }
},
```

Comment: Use Fiddler to observe your request and responses.

Comment: Thanks! since now i'm able to get the access token. I will give this json a try.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that there's a simpler token-issuing URL nowadays.  Your C++ code will look something like this:

```
pplx::task<string_t> getToken()
{
    http_client client(L"https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken");
    http_request req(methods::POST);
    req.headers().add(L"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", YOUR_API_KEY);
    return client.request(req).then([=](http_response response) -> pplx::task<string_t>
    {
        return response.extract_string(true);
    });
}
```

The entire response body is the token unlike the old scheme, which had a JSON response that included the token.

Comment: Thanks! I had got the same from - https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/speech-api/documentation/api-reference-rest/bingvoicerecognition  . It works :)